# Set value for a pointer in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have 2 UIImageVIew:

```
UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

and one UIImage:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithNamed:@"image_name.png"];
```

so i set image for both of UIImageView with the same UIImage:

```
imageView1.image = image;
imageView2.image = image;
```

How can i change value of UIImage *image (Not point **UIImage *image** to another UIImage by: **image = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithNamed:@"another_image_name.png"];**). So when i do it, i want imageView1 and imageView2 display the same image (**another_image_name.png**)

Answer (score 2):

[`UIImage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances are immutable, once they have been `alloc`'d and `init`'d, they cannot change. If you want to change the images for your image views, you need to `alloc` and `init` another UIImage instance (or use the convenience methods, e.g. `+imageNamed:` etc) and set it to both of your image views.

> Image objects are immutable, so you cannot change their properties after creation

Answer (score 0):

You can't modifty a UIImage so what you ask is impossible to do straightforwardly.

However, you could have imageView2 register as an observer on the image property of imageView1y using [key value observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) and when it observes a change it sets its image to the same one as in imageView1.

```
// To register for KVO
[imageView1 addObserver: imageView2
             forKeyPath: @"image"
                options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                context: NULL];
```

In imageView2, you'll need the following.  You can either subclass UIImageView or add a category to it.

```
// method in imageView2 to deal with observations

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString*) keyPath
                      ofObject: (id)object
                        change: (NSDictionary*)change
                       context: (void*) context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"image"]) 
    {
        [self setImage: [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]];
    }
}
```